# Why is the text displaying, but not the textarea field itself?

Tags: metabox

So, I have a textarea as a field in a meta box, if I do this it works OK:

```
 $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'twitter_embed', true);  
echo '<table class="form-table">';   
   echo '<tr>
    <th><label for="twitter_embed">Twitter Embed</label></th>
    <td><textarea name="twitter_embed" id="twitter_embed" cols="60" rows="4">'. 
   $meta 
    . '</textarea>
    <span class="description">Use to embed tweets on your post.</span></td>
    </tr>';
```

It will display `$meta` in the textarea. However, if $meta is empty I want to provide a default value using `get_option`. When I do this (see below), it displays the `get_option` text in the meta box area, but the textarea field is not displayed at all. **So it displays the text  not in the textarea.** Why is this happening? The code that doesn't seem to display the textarea:

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'twitter_embed', true);  
  echo '<table class="form-table">';           
  echo '<tr>
    <th><label for="twitter_embed">Twitter Embed</label></th>
    <td><textarea name="twitter_embed" id="twitter_embed" cols="60" rows="4">'. 
    ($meta ==  '') ? get_option('my_option_name') : $meta 
    . '</textarea>
    <span class="description">Use to embed tweets on your post.</span></td>
    </tr>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a PHP syntax issue, you can't put a ternary operator inside an echo. Assign the value to `$meta` in one line:

```
$meta = '' == get_post_meta($post->ID, 'twitter_embed', true) ? get_option('my_option_name') : get_post_meta($post->ID, 'twitter_embed', true);
```